# How to retrieve mat file data?

Tags: matlab, function

I have a mat file with 10 (columns) x 3 (rows) of data and I would like to retrieve these data to produce some readable output via certain functions. For example, the first column of data is 1 0 0 and the output will be Yes.

May I know how can I perform the first step, which is how to retrieve/read the data from the mat file which saved in laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name of your '.mat' file as 'xyz.mat' and the variable stored in .mat file had same name as the file.

```
load('xyz.mat') % loads xyz.mat into workspace.
if xyz(:,1)==[1;0;0],
answer='yes'
end
```

Note: Here I have assumed that array xyz was stored as xyz.mat , if the array name was different from filename given to the .mat file then you will have to use the array name in the if statement . e.g. if you stored an array named abcd as xyz.mat  then when you use load('xyz.mat') the array gets loaded with its original name (abcd) and not the file name xyz

Comment: It is a way of addressing elements of an array e.g. if you want to access the element in 3rd row ,first column then you would use xyz(3,1). In the example I showed, I am using 1st column of the array xyz hence xyz(:,1).Here : signifies that I want all the row entries corresponding to column 1. If I only wanted to access first two rows then I would have written xyz(1:2,1)].

Comment: when I display the value of xyz using xyz(:,1), the result showed is "[3x1 double]" instead of the value [1:0:0], and perhaps this is the reason when I execute your code and the result is "no". May I know where is the problem?

Comment: "when I display the value of xyz using xyz(:,1), the result showed is "[3x1 double]" -- Thats correct! xyz(:,1) gives elements in all the rows (in this case 3) and first column hence the result is [3x1], there is nothing with that. I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do here. Do you want to assign [1;0;0] to xyz(:,1)? or do you want to check whether xyz(:,1) is [1;0;0]?